# Getting Field 'Title' Required Error on the ScreenResDom part of the button

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

```
If (DataCardValue58.Selected.Value =  "Single" , SubmitForm(Form1),DataCardValue58.Selected.Value = "Married", SubmitForm(Form1) & SubmitForm(Form5) ,SubmitForm(Form1) & SubmitForm(Form4)) & Navigate(ScreenEnd) & SubmitForm(FormResDom)
```

The issue is I am trying to submit multiple forms on one Button over multiple screens. Which are all saving to the one list based off the user() e mail function.

All forms save no problem except the FormResDom, function doesn't draw an error until after it is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

One of the Sharepoint lists you are submitting to has the `Title` column set to `Required`.

**Your options are:**

1. Go to the Sharepoint lists and mark the `Title` column as not required OR
2. Add the `Title` column to the form in PowerApps and give it a value.